# How to make each listbox item have its own value via other controls such as numericUpDown and checkbox?

Tags: c#, dictionary, checkbox, listbox, numericupdown

I am trying to create a program where a `listbox` has a number of items. Each new item has to be automatically intertwined with a `checkbox` and a `numericUpDown`. So for example Item A would have the `checkbox` ticked, with 50 in the `numericUpDown` while Item B will have the `checkbox` unchecked and with 25 in the `numericUpDown` If possible, I would like to do this via `dictionary<>` This is the code I have so far:

The class I have created

```
class MediaClass
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This is my dictionary code

```
public void Dictionary()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, MediaClass>();
    listBox_Movielist.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
}
```

I would also like this to be saved to a text file. My save code is

```
private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefile.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
    savefile.Title = "Save As";
    savefile.ShowDialog();
}
```

My load code is

```
OpenFileDialog loadfile = new OpenFileDialog();
loadfile.DefaultExt = "txt";
loadfile.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
loadfile.FilterIndex = 1;
loadfile.CheckFileExists = true;
loadfile.CheckPathExists = true;
loadfile.Multiselect = false;
loadfile.ShowDialog();
System.IO.StreamReader lText = new
System.IO.StreamReader(loadfile.FileName);
listBox_Movielist.Text = lText.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Do you mean you have `X` number of checkboxes and numericupdowns or just the one that needs to change when selection is changed? For the latter you can just have a `SelectionChanged` event that updates the others. Also, is this winforms?

Comment: @Sayse Yes, you are on the right track. There is one `checkbox` and one `numericUpDown`. I would like their values to change when switching between items in a `listbox`. I am just struggling with how to do it. After that I need to know how to properly save it to a .txt file (as you can see in the code) which will include the `listbox` items and what I am attempting that I explained above.

Comment: You can just use the `SelectionChanged` event of the listbox to update the two controls based on the `SelectedItem` of the listbox

Comment: @Sayse Could you please elaborate? I tried, but my efforts ended in vain. I couldnt get the `SelectionChanged` event for some reason, but I managed to get the `SelectedItem`. I couldn't figure out how to use it though...

Comment: [SelectedValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Still can't get it. Could you provide me with example code? I'm doing this in Winforms.

Comment: The link I provided above contains a complete working example, See `ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged` method for the event

Comment: It did not do what I wanted. Selecting a `listbox` item results in an unhandled exception. `private void listBox_Movielist_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox_Movielist.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                text_Insert.Text = listBox_Movielist.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your ListBox is called listbox, add this in the constructor for your window:

```
listbox.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    var item = listbox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    string media = item.Content as string;
    if (media != null)
    {
        //set checkbox to dictionary[media].Checked
        //set updown to dictionary[media].Number
    }
};
```

I'm not quite sure why you declare your dictionary in an extra method. This will make it impossible to reference outside of that method. What you probably want is to have the dictionary be a private field. Something like

```
private Dictionary<String, MediaClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, MediaClass>();
```

somewhere in your window class.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `SelectionChanged`? It doesn't appear for me.

Comment: @MythrilMagician It doesn't appear? Can you show me the definition of your ListBox?

Comment: If by definition, you mean this: `private void listBox_Movielist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: No, the definition of your ListBox. The code that creates the ListBox (might be in your xaml).

Comment: I have the feeling you are lacking very basic knowledge about WPF, is that correct? The definition of your ListBox should be either something like "<ListBox></ListBox>" in your .xaml-file or something like "ListBox listbox = new ListBox();" in your .cs-file

Comment: I tried searching for it, but was unable to find it. What can I do?

Comment: @MythrilMagician How did you add the ListBox? With a designer of some sort?

Comment: Yeah, I used the designer built into VS. So I'm assuming the definition that you speak of is its default.

Comment: @MythrilMagician If you used a regular ListBox, then there has to be a ListBox tag. Try searching your xaml-file for "<ListBox" (with out the quotation marks). And I suggest you read some basic WPF tutorials to get an idea for what you are doing.

Comment: Where do I find my xaml file? I tried searching for it and even googling how to find it, but didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: uhm it should be the one showing below your designer in VS. If not, take a look at the SolutionExplorer (should be on your right) and look for something like "Window1.xaml"

Comment: I think I just figured out why I can't get to my XAML. I didn't create the program with WPF, just regular Windows Forms.

Comment: @MythrilMagician well then...I have no experience with winform what so ever.